# Dynamically added element is fail to draggable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have added a dynamic content using below snap

```
var obj = {"Test Tube": "test.png","Beater": "beat.png"};
    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
        $(".instruments").append('<div class="tile bg-gray">'
                                    +'<div class="tile-content image">'
                                        +'<img src="'+value+'">'
                                    +'</div>'
                                    +'<div class="brand">'
                                        +'<span class="label fg-white">'+key+'</span>'
                                    +'</div>'
                                    +'</div>');
    });

    $(".tile").click(function(){ 
        var imgSelected = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $(".working-area").append('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="border:solid 1px;"><img src="'+imgSelected+'" width="100px" height="100px" /></div>');      
    });
```

Now I need to make newly added #draggable div to be draggable element. for this purpose i have code like below

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

But it works for static elements not work for dynamically added divs like id #draggable

I have link these external js and css

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I don't no why this is wrong for dynamic divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that ,

```
$(function() {
     $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

is equivalent of `$( document ).ready()`. So, when this method is called.. only those elements present at that time will be initialized with `draggable` behavior.And other dynamic element will be be devoid of this initialization.

So, you have to re-initialize `draggable` when those dynamic elements are added ,

```
 $(".tile").click(function(){ 
            var imgSelected = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
            $(".working-area").append('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="border:solid 1px;"><img src="'+imgSelected+'" width="100px" height="100px" /></div>');   
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        });
```

And, Also I suggest you to use **class** selector instead of **id** selector for initializing `draggable`.

Looking at this block of code, it seems the `id` parameter might be duplicate in DOM , which is not good practice. `id` are meant to be unique, and this will cause only one element to be `draggable`.

```
 $(".tile").click(function(){ 
        var imgSelected = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        //FIXME : Chance of Duplicate id
        $(".working-area").append('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="border:solid 1px;"><img src="'+imgSelected+'" width="100px" height="100px" /></div>');      
    });
```